# SwiftUI: Animate list after ObservedObject updates

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am attempting to animate the insertions of listItems in a List after fetching data from an API. I first show a ProgressView when the app starts calling the API, and then displays the list after API call returns.

Currently, my implementation results in a `tableView.reloadData()` like animation which causes a visual jerk. I would like to achieve a soft animation by using `.animation(.default)`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var manager = APIManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if manager.isLoading {
                    ProgressView()
                } else {
                    List(0..<20) { i in
                        Text("\(i)")
                            .animation(.default)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Items")
        }
    }
}

class APIManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading = false
    
    init() {
        fetchData()
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        isLoading = true
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            withAnimation {
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `withAnimation {}` wrapping -

```
func fetchData() {
    isLoading = true
        
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        // no animation needed
        // withAnimation {
            self.isLoading = false
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before but it still gives the `reloadData()` animation.